# create UML Diagrams with netbeans 7.1.2

Tags: netbeans

I am using netbeans 7.1.2 to create my GUI application. I would like to know how to create a class diagram from my source code (reverse engineering) because i do not see any plug in information on the web. If anyone has any experience with this software please let me know

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of NetBeans does not have this feature. Version 6.7 and earlier included this feature. If I remember correctly you had the ability to sync changes both ways.

More here: http://netbeans.org/features/uml/

Comment: so are you saying i should use jDeveloper instead?

Comment: If you have an existing project already in NetBeans you could use the old and the new version of NetBeans. Just open the old NetBeans when you want to edit the UML diagram and sync changes.

Comment: so your saying i use the old version of netbeans and add the uml plug in and then create my UML Diagram. Ho will i sync the changes

Comment: You open the new project in the old NB and configure the UML project to sync with it.

Comment: how do i configure the UML feature. It seems like there has to be an extra plug in feature